# C Control Strings?

Tags: c, string, controls

I know that in other languages such as Java when I use System.out.println(); and I put a variable inside of it like an int that holds the number 22 it will print 22 to the console.

In C if I do the same thing with printf(); I need to specify the type in the string such as printf("%d", n); I also know that Java has its own printf function.

What I am trying to get at here is how the C control String works compared to other languages such as Java where you don't have to provide the type identifier in the System.out.println(); and it automatically recognizes the variable is an int.

Is this part of C's way of efficiency and does it not actually check the type and rely's on the programmer to understand the type they are providing?

Comment: Java have something called [*reflection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) that it can use to learn the types of variables. C doesn't have that.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `printf` is neither efficient nor type-safe way of writing data.

There is a performance penalty because format string is parsed at compile time and type specific actions are chosen at run time as well, whereas in C++ and Java it can be done at compile time. Moreover, variadic arguments are forced to be passed on the stack, that is less efficient than passing them in registers.

And what is even more important is that `printf` is not type-safe. It is possible to pass any number of parameters of any types to `printf`, ignoring format string prescriptions. Of course, it can easily trigger undefined behavior.

The only reason for such behavior is that there is no function overloading in C.

On the other hand, it's not that bad. First, most of the compilers parse format string and issue a warning if it isn't consistent with parameters passed to `printf`. Second, aforementioned performance penalty is in fact negligible compared to the cost of formatting and printing text after types have been deduced.

Answer (score 1):

Both C's predefined data types (integers, characters, etc.) as well as user defined types carry no type information with them at run-time.  Thus if you use a 4 byte integer in your code, it occupies only 4 bytes in memory (disregarding any padding needed for alignment).  This is great for efficiency reasons, but it means that functions that handle multiple data types (like printf) need to be told via the format/control string what the types of the arguments are.

So when printf receives a format string of "%d %f" it knows that the type of the first non-format argument is integer and the second argument is of type float.

Comment: In that last sentence, I would hesitate to state "it *knows*". A better description would be "it does *not* know". `printf` *assumes* that you (the programmer) are feeding in the right argument types for each format specifier in the formatting string.

Answer (score 0):

By passing control characters in printf() we tell the compiler how to allocate the memory and what is the range of the data that we wanna to print.

Answer (score -1):

Control strings are also known as format specifiers. They are used in formatted input and output operations of the data. Remember, format specifiers are used for formatting the data, for example, in  `printf()` and `scanf()`.

Control strings in `scanf()` are used to transfer the data to the processor's memory  in a formatted way, whereas `printf ()` transfers the data to the output device e.g. monitor screen in a formatted way.

Some common Format Specifierss are listed below:

```
________________________________________________________________
FORMAT SPECIFIER               ::          DESCRIPTION
________________________________________________________________
%c                                          Character       
%d                                       Signed Integer 

%e or %E                              Scientific notation

%f                                       Floating point

%g or %G.                             Similar as %e or %E

%hi.                                     Signed Integer

%hu                                 Unsigned Integer(Short) 

%i                                       Signed Integer

%l or %ld or %li                         Signed Integer

%lf                                      Floating point

%Lf                                      Floating point 

%lu                                     Unsigned integer

%lli, %lld                            Signed long long int

%llu.                                unsigned long long int

%o.                              Octal representation of Integer.

%p                              Address of pointer to void void *   
                                              void *

%s                                       String char *
%u                                       Unsigned int 

                                      Unsigned short int 

%n                                      Prints nothing

%%                                    Prints % character

%o                                   Octal representation 

%p                            Address of pointer to void void * 
                                             void *

%s                                       String char *

%u                                     Unsigned Integer 

%x or %X                         Hexadecimal representation of 
                                         Unsigned Int.

%n                                      Prints nothing  

%%                                   Prints % character
________________________________________________________________
```